# error running my first app on ruby on rails regarding rake gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

I recently installed ruby on rail and I'm attempting to create my first app, after running it in command prompt every thing was fine till the end, it said make sure that 'install gem rake -v '10.4.2' is successful before my app can run. i'm completely lost...please help!!!

Comment: What is the error and what is your question?

Comment: c:\Sites>rails -v
DL is deprecated, Please use Fiddle
rails 4.1.8
this is what happens when I try to see what version of rails i have

Comment: c:\Sites>rails -v
DL is deprecated, Please use Fiddle
rails 4.1.8

and then I tried to create my first app, it ran and this was the error after it ran:
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Resolving dependences...

Gem: :RemoteFetcher: :FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed <https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.2>

An error occurred while installing rake <10.4.2>, and bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that 'gem install rake -v '10.4.2'' succeeds before bundling

Comment: I don't know if that helps but that is as specific as I can get because I'm an amateur at this LOL...how do I resolve this problem

Comment: I figured it out, thank you